# Unable to set up video call using Turn Server

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

Please please help in setting up Turn server in Ubuntu, such that we can have video call even connecting  from different network.

I have installed using below command in Ubuntu 20.10 :
sudo apt-get install Coturn.

Can any one suggest how I should configure turn server to achieve above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should start looking at the [example configuration](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/examples/etc/turnserver.conf).

Adapt it your your needs (host public IP address and realm), then restart coturn.

Then you can test it with tools like [test.webrtc](https://test.webrtc.org/) and [WebRTC sample for Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) (or your own client application).